# join and sort data in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to sort data by joined collections field. I can do that in `mysql` like that:

```
SELECT A.name, B.address
FROM user as A
JOIN user_details as B
     ON(A.id=B.uid)
WHERE A.status=1
ORDER BY B.modifiedDate DESC
```

but How can i do that in MongoDB?

### **UPDATED**

### User:

```
id      name    status  created_at
---------------------------------------
1      Shail    1   2/16/2017 6:40
---------------------------------------
2      Paras    1   2/16/2017 5:40
```

### UserDetails

```
id    address   uid modifiedDate
--------------------------------
1     Addres1   1   2/16/2017 10:40
--------------------------------
2     Addres2   2   2/16/2017 10:35
```

### Expected Result:

```
id  name    modifiedDate
------------------------------
1   Paras   2/16/2017 10:35
------------------------------
2   Shail   2/16/2017 10:40
```

[UPDATE 2]

I have tried to do that in MongoDB by using `Aggregate Frameworks` Like that :

```
                 [
              {
                "$match": {
                  "status": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "$lookup": {
                  "from": "user_details",
                  "localField": "uid",
                  "foreignField": "id",
                  "as": "userdetails"
                }
              },
              {
                "$unwind": "userdetails"
              },
              {
                "$sort": {
                  "$userdetails.modifiedDate": 1,
                  "posts": 1
                }
              }
            ]

        **ERROR :**


        > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message
        > '127.0.0.1:27017: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.'
```

Comment: And it didn't work because...

Comment: @israel.zinc - thats what i'm looking for

Comment: What output or error did you get?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I wasn't verbose enough. What is the error message? Did you run and it didn't work?

Comment: Can you please post how your data look like?

Comment: Please check my updated question with Error Msg..

Comment: @israel.zinc - I want all users who have recently updated their profile.

Comment: The error message says it all, in your `$sort` pipeline step `{
    "$sort": {
      "$userdetails.modifiedDate": 1,
      "posts": 1
    }
  }` you have a field name `userdetails` that starts with `$`. If you remove that to become `{
    "$sort": {
      "userdetails.modifiedDate": 1,
      "posts": 1
    }
  }` you shouldn't get any errors.

Comment: I was about to say the same as @chridam

Comment: yes i know that.. but My Question is How Can i Make it Work? I have posted everything in my question what i hv tried. and when i removed that `$` it gives me no error but i'm not getting result as i want.

Comment: Based on the aggregate query that you have posted before `"localField": "uid","foreignField": "id"`. The local field is the field from `user` should be `id` and `foreignField` should be `uid`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram for notifying me that. but still i'm not able to get the result..

Comment: Add some sample documents from both your collections that you are expecting your query to return.

Comment: @Veeram - i have added the collection and documents now you can check..

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness please add your current mongo query to the post

Comment: You should merge those collections, Document orientated databases should not be used like relational databases. It's wrong usage of the database itself.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Yes i know that. i'm looking for some solution like Is it possible to do that or not?

Comment: @veeram - i have posted my query and error msg.. i know the error but i dont know the how to query in that kind situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query.

Changes -

`$lookup` to switch the local field and foreign field.

`$unwind` to include `$` reference.

`$sort` to remove the `$` reference.

```
 [{
    "$match": {
        "status": 1
    }
 }, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "user_details",
        "localField": "id",
        "foreignField": "uid",
        "as": "userdetails"
    }
 }, {
    "$unwind": "$userdetails"
 }, {
    "$sort": {
        "userdetails.modifiedDate": 1
    }
 }]
```

Comment: yes i have  tried that but i am not getting sorted data

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the data wont be sorted. Is `modifiedDate` field a date type in mongodb ?